# Multiple SQL Statements in Java (with ?allowMultiQueries=true)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a question. I work with a lot of SQL Queries and try to work out the best and fastest solution to handle a lot of queries (about 10'000 SQL-queries). I have figured out 2 ways of doing this and would like to hear your opinion on this. **VERSION1**: loop over prepared statements, **VERSION2**: allow multiple queries divided by semicolon (by adding "?allowMultiQueries=true" when connecting to the database).

Version2 worked out much faster (3 seconds) wheras Version1 was pretty slow (over 1 minute). So my question is, are there any downsides (or maybe safety concerns) about allowing multiple prepared statements? 

Heres a short code example. Thx for all help!

```
// i want to execute the following 3 SQL queries:
String[] SQL = new String[3];
SQL[0] = "UPDATE tbl1 SET age=22 WHERE id=1;";
SQL[1] = "UPDATE tbl1 SET age=80 WHERE id=2;";
SQL[2] = "UPDATE tbl1 SET age=31 WHERE id=3;";

// VERSION1: loop over prepared statements
int[] age = {22,80,31};
int[] id  = { 1, 2, 3};
Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://EXAMPLE", "user", "pw");
PreparedStatement stmt1_P = conn1.prepareStatement("UPDATE tbl1 SET age=? WHERE id=?;");
for (int i=0; i<SQL.length; i++) {
    stmt1_P.setInt(1, age[i]);
    stmt1_P.setInt(2, id[i]);
    stmt1_P.executeUpdate();
}               

// VERSION2: multiple queries divided by semicolon
Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://EXAMPLE?allowMultiQueries=true", "user", "pw");
Statement stmt2 = conn2.createStatement();
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<SQL.length; i++) {
    s.append(SQL[i]);
}
stmt2.executeUpdate(s.toString());
```

Comment: Are you committing the transaction between the prepared writes?

Comment: Every database imposes a limit on the length of an sql query or statement in general. This means that you will get an SQL exception if your query is too long. Also, even if it's not too long , you might face some perfomance issues. For updates, esepcially when the update is of the same form, the recommended way is to use batch updates

Comment: @dsp_user oke thx for that information! But when the query is too long ALL the statements wont work and i will get an error message, right? Or is it possible that only a few of the commands (lets say the first 5'000) seperated by semicolon will be executed and the rest (the other 5'000) wont be? thx for your help!

Comment: If you execute all your statements as part of  a transaction, then either all will succeed or all will fail (because that's how a transaction works). If your statements are not part of a transaction, then it depends on how you code them. If your statements are inside of a try block and the catch block doesn't throw exceptions (but rather "handles" them), then all your statements that doesn't throw an exception will succeed. If they are not inside a try block, then only the statements up to the first statement that throws an exception will succeed (the others will not even execute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenating statements is generally a good idea. As you've discovered, they generate less network traffic and are faster.

I don't see any security concerns to worry about.

One suggestion to think about: integrity. If one of your many concatenated statements fails (for whatever reason) you may have some difficulty figuring out which one failed and which ones succeeded. If you wrap each bunch of concatenated statements in a transaction, you can use `ROLLBACK` to restore the state of your database if any statements in your bunch fail.

Comment: For updates, the recommended way is to use batch updates (it's possible then to see which updates have failed)